# Using getString() in a class

Tags: android, class, android-activity, android-context, r.java-file

I have a class where I should insert some strings (taken from strings.xml) into a `StringBuffer`. That will be pass to an Activity. The problem is that I should use getString() method, but I can't because it's a class. What can I do?

I tried passing it the context of the activity like this:

```
MainActivity aq = new MainActivity();
Context ctx = aq.getApplicationContext();

this.primo= this.primo.append(ctx.getString(R.string.A)+ "\n");
```

But the app crash when the string is going to be printed.
And makes this exception:

```
11-07 16:50:56.750: E/AndroidRuntime(11871): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-07 16:50:56.750: E/AndroidRuntime(11871): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-07 16:50:56.750: E/AndroidRuntime(11871):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:100)
11-07 16:50:56.750: E/AndroidRuntime(11871):    at com.example.test.Mainclass.<init>(Mainclass.java:130)
11-07 16:50:56.750: E/AndroidRuntime(11871):    at com.example.test.MainActivity.calcolatore(MainActivity.java:534)
11-07 16:50:56.750: E/AndroidRuntime(11871):    at com.example.test.MainActivity$18.onClick(MainActivity.java:500)
11-07 16:50:56.750: E/AndroidRuntime(11871):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
11-07 16:50:56.750: E/AndroidRuntime(11871):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
11-07 16:50:56.750: E/AndroidRuntime(11871):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-07 16:50:56.750: E/AndroidRuntime(11871):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-07 16:50:56.750: E/AndroidRuntime(11871):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-07 16:50:56.750: E/AndroidRuntime(11871):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
11-07 16:50:56.750: E/AndroidRuntime(11871):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 16:50:56.750: E/AndroidRuntime(11871):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-07 16:50:56.750: E/AndroidRuntime(11871):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
11-07 16:50:56.750: E/AndroidRuntime(11871):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
11-07 16:50:56.750: E/AndroidRuntime(11871):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I suppose it's Android code? Can you add more information? Are you sure that primo and ctx are not null?

Comment: Yes, it is. Sure I added the log errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import the following in your Java Class

```
import android.content.res.Resources;
```

And use this method to get string:

```
Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.stringname);
```